# How to define limit is not L using epsilon-delta?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x)$ be a function, $x \in D$.
If for some $\epsilon >0$, there exists no $\delta >0$ such that for every $x \in D$, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$,
then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq L$.
This is what we use to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq L$.

Is the converse of this statement also true? ie,
If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq L$, can we say that, for some $\epsilon >0$, there exists no $\delta >0$ such that for every $x \in D$, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

If not, could you give an example where the statement is false? What is the intuition behind this? Also, what is the definition of limit is not L?
I see a definition [here](https://socratic.org/questions/what-does-limit-does-not-exist-mean), which begins, "there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $\delta >0$...". Can we instead form a definition that begins, "for some $\epsilon >0$, there exists no $\delta >0$ such that..." ?

Comment: I find it weird to leave things "half-negated" in the form of "there is no $\delta>0$...". I much rather phrase things in the positive sense: "$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\neq L$ means that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there is some $x\in D$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-L|\geq \epsilon$".

Comment: If I were to phrase it as "there exists no $\delta >0$ such that ....", how would I complete this definition?

Comment: what you said is correct. "There is an $\epsilon >0$ for which there is no $\delta>0$ such that for every $x\in D$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$".

Comment: Should be possible to go back-and-forth by just using DeMorgan's laws: $\lnot(\forall x)P(x)$ is equivalent to $(\exists x)\lnot P(x)$, and $\lnot(\exists x)P(x)$ is equivalent to $(\forall x)\lnot P(x)$. Also, if two formulae are equivalent, so are their negations: $P(x)\iff Q(x)$ is equivalent to $\lnot P(x)\iff \lnot Q(x)$. There is nothing here specific to convergence or limits.

Comment: In other words, the negation of $$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x, 0<|x-a|<\delta) |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ is $$(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x, 0<|x-a|<\delta) |f(x)-L|\ge\epsilon$$ You can read the latter sentence in many ways.

Comment: @StinkingBishop right, but I wasn't sure if the converse statement is true. So to conclude, the following statements is true -  
If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq L$, then, for some $\epsilon >0$, there exists no $\delta >0$ such that for every $x \in D$, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @Mehnaz I've turned my comments into an answer, have a look. I've covered your particular statement and another equivalent statement, and have also got a little exercise for you.

Comment: TL;DR You can apply De Morgan's laws to the negation of the original sentence $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ up to three times, every time you get a different but equivalent sentence. Yours is obtained when you apply the laws once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments: there is nothing here specific to convergence or limits. It is pure mathematical logic (more precisely: [predicate logic or first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic)).

First of all, [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic) state that: $\lnot(\forall x)P(x)$ is equivalent to $(\exists x)\lnot P(x)$, and $\lnot(\exists x)P(x)$ is equivalent to $(\forall x)\lnot P(x)$.

This is also valid if we use the constrained quantifiers such as $(\forall x>0)P(x)$. In fact, $(\forall x: P(x))Q(x)$ is just a shorthand for writing $(\forall x)(P(x)\implies Q(x))$ and $(\exists x: P(X))Q(x)$ is a shorthand for writing $(\exists x)(P(x)\land Q(x))$. Thus, for example, the following sentences are equivalent:

$$\begin{array}{c} \lnot(\forall x: P(x))Q(x)\\\lnot (\forall x)(P(x)\implies Q(x))\\(\exists x)\lnot(P(x)\implies Q(x))\\(\exists x)(P(x)\land\lnot Q(x))\\(\exists x: P(x))\lnot Q(x)\end{array}$$

and, similarly, $\lnot(\exists x: P(x))Q(x)$ can be shown to be equivalent to $(\forall x: P(x))\lnot Q(x)$.

---

Now, the definition of "*$f(x)$ converges to $L$ when $x\to a$*" (i.e. of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$) is:

$$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x: x\in D, |x-a|<\delta)|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

*We are interested in how we can negate this sentence.*

> (Note that *I would refrain from writing $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne L$* because such writing is *ambiguous*: it is not clear whether it means
>
> - "When $x\to a$, $f(x)$ converges to something that is not $L$"
>
> or it means
>
> - "When $x\to a$, $f(x)$ does not converge to $L$".
>
> The latter is the negation we are looking for here; the former is a different statement, in general not equivalent to the latter.)

So, applying De Morgan's laws (three times in a row), the negation is:

$$(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x: x\in D, |x-a|<\delta)|f(x)-L|\ge\epsilon$$

(also turning $<$ into $\ge$ in the last bit). If you want to translate this to English, you would say:

> There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that, for all $\delta>0$ there is an $x\in D$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-L|\ge \epsilon$.

However, applying De Morgan's laws partially would produce other equivalent sentences, such as the following (applying the laws once):

$$(\exists\epsilon>0)\lnot(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x: x\in D, |x-a|<\delta)|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

> There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no $\delta>0$ with the property that, for all $x\in D$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$"

(had to insert "with the property" to make it sound a bit nicer, but this is essentially your example from the question).

**Exercise** Try to apply De Morgan's laws twice. What sentence do you get, and how would you translate it to English?

Comment: To answer the exercise, would it be: $$(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x: x\in D, |x-a|<\delta)\lnot(|f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$$ 
In English - 
There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in D$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ but not $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Ahm... you applied it three times. I was thinking of $$(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)\lnot(\forall x:x\in D, |x-a|<\delta)|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ i.e. "There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ it's that *not* for all $x\in D$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ we will have $|f(x)-L$<\epsilon$" ... or something like that.